# extract timestamp from EPOCH cloumn from postgresql DB table

Tags: postgresql, epoch

I am trying to execute below-mentioned PostgreSQL query and in which checkin_ts in epoch format and want to write a query which is humanly understandable(putting timestamp in human readable format).

```
select * from users where to_timestamp(checkin_ts) >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00'
LIMIT 100;
```

when I tried to execute the above query then I get the following error

```
ERROR:  execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway
```

Comment: Show us your **complete** code. There is no `execute` in your question (and the error message is not a Postgres error message)

Comment: Are you running this as part of an application? Are you able to reproduce this if you run the SQL manually, e.g. using `psql` or pgAdmin? Your error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the SQL shown, and sounds like it's a problem with your application using asynchronous queries incorrectly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am running in PgAdmin 4 workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give us the description of your table, to know checkin_ts format.

But to_timestamp need to text paramaters like this :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE to_timestamp(checkin_ts::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00' LIMIT 100;
```

And what is your environment to execute this query ?
The error seems to be that you are trying to execute two queries on the same connection using two different cursors.

Comment: i get the following error ERROR:  timestamp out of range
SQL state: 22008

Comment: Again what do you have in your field checkin_ts exactly ? Show us some data, please.

Comment: Piedvache  this is the table description

Comment: id | name | checkin_ts

Comment: integer | character varying | integer

Comment: OK so if checkin_ts is an interger, these mean it's timestamp since 01/01/1970 ? If so, you can convert this to timestamp PostgreSQL format like this : SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +  checkin_ts * INTERVAL '1 second'; and then do your test of the result to be >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00' ...